# Normal unit vector of shape operator

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curves, surfaces, vector-fields

Let $\alpha$ be curve in $M ⊆ \mathbb R^3$ where $M$ is asurface . If $U$ is unit normal of $M$ restricted to the curve a then $S(\alpha')=-U'$ where $S$ is the shape operator and it's defin8ed by $(S_p(v)=-∇_v(U))$ and $∇_v(U)$ is the covariant derivative of $U$ with respect to $v$ .
I tried to use the definition of covariant derivative at a point $p$ which is $U(p+t\alpha')'(0)$ and then apply the chain rule so I get the following $S_p(α')=α'U'(p)$ could any one give a hint ?

Comment: You need to set up what your notation means. In particular, $M$ is a surface. What does $U'$ actually mean? Hint: It is shorthand for $(U\circ\alpha)'$. What is the definition of the shape operator?

Comment: @TedShifrin I have modified the question and defined the shape operator it's also named as Weingarten endomorphism . Any way  it's -∇v(U) at apoint p       
 - covariant derivative of  U with respect v at apoint p

Comment: When you wrote down the chain rule, what you wrote is meaningless. Rewrite $(U\circ\alpha)’(t)$ as $\nabla_{\alpha’(t)}U$.

Comment: @TedShifrin i think i got it . Instead of α'U'(p)  
i should write α'U'(α)which is equal to (U○α)'(t) did you mean that ?

Comment: Review the chain rule carefully.

Comment: @TedShifrin itried again to solve this problem , using the lemma 4.6 in elementry diffrential geometry by barret O'nell $\alpha'(t)[f]=\frac{d(f(\alpha))}{dt}(t)\implies \nabla_{\alpha'(t)}U=(α'(t)[U_1],α'(t)[U_2],α'(t)[U_3])=(\frac{d}{dt} U_1(α(t)),\frac{d}{dt}U_2(α(t)),\frac{d}{dt}U_3(α(t)))=(U'_1,U'_2,U'_3)=U'$ i  .Is  my attempt correct ?

Comment: The point is that the notation $f'$ (or $U'$) for $(f\circ\alpha)'$ (or $(U\circ\alpha)')$ is sloppy and confuses people. But, nevertheless, we all use it. Writing out $U$ in terms of components doesn't help, but, yes, you have it right.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you professor Theodore Shifrin .I'am intrested in diffrential geometry problems especially those that are related to the topics of curves( Frenet frame,parametrized curves ...) and surfaces (shape operator normal gaussian and mean curvature...). i would be thank full if you help me getting some books or questions on those topics.

Comment: Download my (free) differential geometry text, linked in my profile. You will find hundreds of exercises.